# Is this copy assignment operation safe?

Tags: c++, memory-corruption, copy-assignment

```
#include<string>

class HasPtr {
public:
    HasPtr(const std::string &s = std::string()) :
        ps(new std::string(s)), i(0) {}
    HasPtr(const HasPtr &orig) :ps(new std::string(*orig.ps)), i(orig.i) {}
    HasPtr &operator=(const HasPtr &rhs) {
        *ps = *rhs.ps;
        i = rhs.i;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    std::string *ps;
    int i;
};
```

When I assign a HasPtr whose data member ps points to a large string to another,
is there any the possibility that I cause a memory corruption? for example:

```
HasPtr a;
HasPtr b(string("123456789...123456789"));
a=b;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold the `std::string` by value. Besides being a string abstraction, it's also a resource management class, so use it as such. If you do, your class will be rule of 0/3/5 compliant without any extra effort from you.

Comment: what is  0/3/5 compliant? I google it and can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

The shown code is missing a destructor, this is going to result in a memory leak.

After the appropriate destructor gets added, the resulting class [will be perfectly Rule-Of-Three compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). As such, there won't be any memory-related issues.

Comment: I use the synthesized destructor. My question is the safety about my copy assignment  operation.

Comment: *I use the synthesized destructor* -- Which is not the correct thing to do. --  *My question is the safety about my copy assignment operation* -- It is not safe, as it leaks memory.  Why not do as the answer given states?  Add a destructor, implement the rule of 3 using simple swaps, and you're good to go.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know the Rule of Three, okay I can add a destructor, but what confuse me is that the left-hand-side HasPtr 's data member pointed to a empty string before, it pointed to a place in a dynamic memory, my copy assignment operation copys a large string to that place, and I don't know whether the process is safe or not.

Comment: @K.Robert If what you want is a single string that's shared, then the string member should have been `std::shared_ptr<std::string>`, not a raw pointer.  As it stands now, there is a memory leak as you wrote no code to `delete` that memory at some point.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie What you say is right, but it doesn't answer my question.Thank you, I think I have found my answer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the copy assignment does not leak memory.

Answer (score 0):

When `std::string` use up the memory during the operation, an exception will throw out, so the process doesn't corrupt the memory.